# Qt 5.13 Oracle OCI Result cannot bind to return a SYS_REFCURSOR

Tags: oracle, qt, qt5, oracle-call-interface

I recently built Qt 5.13 statically, along with qsqloci plugin and it came out pretty well. One of the issues I have been working around is how to return a SYS_REFCURSOR object from Oracle base to a QSqlResult or something similar. I found a patch https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-166

I have tried the exact same thing, but somehow, it managed to print out:

ORA-01008: not all variables bound
Unable to execute statement.

I have a crystal clear connection to database and I can execute other statements, as well, not a problem. The only problem is how to return a SYS_REFCURSOR.

Thank you.

```
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(QOCIResult *)

QOCIResult *p_cursor = reinterpret_cast<QOCIResult*>(db.driver()->createResult());

QSqlQuery content_query(db);
content_query.prepare("begin ispovedi.get_ord_kategorii_list(:p_cursor); end;");
content_query.addBindValue(qVariantFromValue(p_cursor), QSql::Out);

if (content_query.exec())
{
     p_cursor->exec();
}
else
{
     qCritical("%s.", qPrintable(content_query.lastError().text()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I try to migrate the patch https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-166 to Qt 5.7 yesterday, and it seems to work, here is my patch:

```
--- qsql_oci.cpp.orig   Thu Aug 29 05:18:48 2019
+++ qsql_oci.cpp    Thu Aug 29 11:53:44 2019
@@ -82,6 +82,9 @@

 //#define QOCI_DEBUG

+Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(QSqlResult *)
+
+
 Q_DECLARE_OPAQUE_POINTER(OCIEnv*);
 Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(OCIEnv*)
 Q_DECLARE_OPAQUE_POINTER(OCIStmt*);
@@ -206,6 +209,8 @@
     QVariant lastInsertId() const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
     bool execBatch(bool arrayBind = false) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
     void virtual_hook(int id, void *data) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
+    bool isCursor;
+    bool internal_prepare();
 };

 class QOCIResultPrivate: public QSqlCachedResultPrivate
@@ -389,6 +394,18 @@
                              const_cast<OCIRowid **>(&rptr->id),
                              -1,
                              SQLT_RDD, indPtr, 0, 0, 0, 0, OCI_DEFAULT);
+        } else if (val.canConvert<QSqlResult *>() && isOutValue(pos)) {
+            QOCIResult *res = (QOCIResult *)qvariant_cast<QSqlResult *>(val);
+
+            if (res->internal_prepare()) {
+                r = OCIBindByPos(sql, hbnd, err,
+                                 pos + 1,
+                                const_cast<OCIStmt **>(&res->d_func()->sql),
+                                 (sb4)0,
+                                 SQLT_RSET, indPtr, 0, 0, 0, 0, OCI_DEFAULT);
+
+                res->isCursor = true;
+            }
         } else {
             qWarning("Unknown bind variable");
             r = OCI_ERROR;
@@ -1833,6 +1850,7 @@
 QOCIResult::QOCIResult(const QOCIDriver *db)
     : QSqlCachedResult(*new QOCIResultPrivate(this, db))
 {
+    isCursor = false;
 }

 QOCIResult::~QOCIResult()
@@ -1931,13 +1949,15 @@
     return rowCount;
 }

-bool QOCIResult::prepare(const QString& query)
-{
+bool QOCIResult::internal_prepare() {
     Q_D(QOCIResult);
     int r = 0;
-    QSqlResult::prepare(query);
+    QString noStr;
+    QSqlResult::prepare(noStr);

-    delete d->cols;
+    if (d->cols)
+        delete d->cols;
+
     d->cols = 0;
     QSqlCachedResult::cleanup();

@@ -1946,20 +1966,36 @@
         if (r != OCI_SUCCESS)
             qOraWarning("QOCIResult::prepare: unable to free statement handle:", d->err);
     }
-    if (query.isEmpty())
-        return false;
+
     r = OCIHandleAlloc(d->env,
                        reinterpret_cast<void **>(&d->sql),
                        OCI_HTYPE_STMT,
                        0,
                        0);
+
     if (r != OCI_SUCCESS) {
         qOraWarning("QOCIResult::prepare: unable to alloc statement:", d->err);
         setLastError(qMakeError(QCoreApplication::translate("QOCIResult",
                      "Unable to alloc statement"), QSqlError::StatementError, d->err));
         return false;
     }
+
     d->setStatementAttributes();
+
+    return true;
+}
+
+bool QOCIResult::prepare(const QString& query)
+{
+    Q_D(QOCIResult);
+
+    if (query.isEmpty())
+        return false;
+
+    if (!internal_prepare())
+        return false;
+
+    int r = 0;
     const OraText *txt = reinterpret_cast<const OraText *>(query.utf16());
     const int len = query.length() * sizeof(QChar);
     r = OCIStmtPrepare(d->sql,
@@ -2020,23 +2056,26 @@
         return false;
     }

-    // execute
-    r = OCIStmtExecute(d->svc,
-                       d->sql,
-                       d->err,
-                       iters,
-                       0,
-                       0,
-                       0,
-                       mode);
-    if (r != OCI_SUCCESS && r != OCI_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) {
-        qOraWarning("QOCIResult::exec: unable to execute statement:", d->err);
-        setLastError(qMakeError(QCoreApplication::translate("QOCIResult",
-                     "Unable to execute statement"), QSqlError::StatementError, d->err));
-#ifdef QOCI_DEBUG
-        qDebug() << "lastQuery()" << lastQuery();
-#endif
-        return false;
+    if (!isCursor)
+    {
+        // execute
+        r = OCIStmtExecute(d->svc,
+                           d->sql,
+                           d->err,
+                           iters,
+                           0,
+                           0,
+                           0,
+                           mode);
+        if (r != OCI_SUCCESS && r != OCI_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) {
+            qOraWarning("QOCIResult::exec: unable to execute statement:", d->err);
+            setLastError(qMakeError(QCoreApplication::translate("QOCIResult",
+                         "Unable to execute statement"), QSqlError::StatementError, d->err));
+    #ifdef QOCI_DEBUG
+            qDebug() << "lastQuery()" << lastQuery();
+    #endif
+            return false;
+        }
     }

     if (stmtType == OCI_STMT_SELECT) {
```

Modify your code as follows and have a try:

```
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(QSqlResult *)

QSqlResult *p_cursor = db.driver()->createResult();

QSqlQuery content_query(db);
content_query.prepare("begin ispovedi.get_ord_kategorii_list(:p_cursor); end;");
content_query.addBindValue(qVariantFromValue(p_cursor), QSql::Out);

if (content_query.exec())
{
     QSqlQuery result_query(p_cursor);
     result_query.exec();
}
else
{
     qCritical("%s.", qPrintable(content_query.lastError().text()));
}
```